# using bind vs using pointers with random number generators

Tags: c++, c++11

I had the following implementation in my code:

```
 // first solution 
 //random.h
class Random{
public:
    std::mt19937* gen;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double>* dis; 
}
//random.cpp
Random::Random()
  {
        std::mt19937_64::result_type seed = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
        gen = new std::mt19937(seed);
        dis = new std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(0.0,1.0);
  }
double Random::next()
  {
        double rand  = 0;
        rand_int = (*dis)(*gen);
        return rand;
  }
```

On the other hand someone else in the company did a different implementation, where he used the `bind` feature from c++11 as follows:

```
// second solution
//random.h
class Random{
public:
    std::function<double()> real_rand;
}
//random.cpp
Random::Random()
 {
       std::mt19937_64::result_type seed = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
       real_rand = std::bind(std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(0.0,1.0), mt19937_64(seed))

 }
 double Random::next()
 {
    double rand  = 0;
    rand = real_rand();
    return rand;
 }
```

Taking into account that you are supposed to have only one PRNG object, and you are supposed to seed it once, then you call that object every time you need a new random number, as the seed is used to create a series of random numbers in the PRNG. I can clearly see this being the case for the first solution.
The question is, how is `bind()` working behind the scenes? Is it creating a new object on every call? Is it really calling the `(constructor)` or the `function()`? How can it tell which one to call? Are there any differences between the solutions?

Comment: The old adage "you are supposed to have only one PRNG object" thankfully disappeared with the advent of the random number library of C++11.

Comment: @Bathsheba can you please elaborate ? reference ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::bind` generates a function object which encapsulates the arguments provided to it. In effect your colleague's code generates the following object:

```
struct random_call
{
  random_call(unsigned seed)
  : _mt19937_64(seed)
  , _uniform_real(0.0, 1.0)
  {}

  double operator() {
    return _uniform_real(_mt19937_64);
  }

  std::mt19937_64 _mt19937_64;
  std::uniform_real_distribution<double> _uniform_real;
};
```

so it looks ok (and actually pretty clever) to me!

One caveat is that you probably wouldn't want to make any copies of the binder object - even if it turns out to be copyable, copying it and then calling `operator()` on the original and the copy will yield the same numbers.

Comment: @BinaryA there surely are. You don't have to bother with deallocation (calling `delete` on the pointers) and all ownership stuff, and you save one level of indirection.

Comment: absolutely. Pointers are evil since they require memory allocation, lifetime management and they also require dereferencing on each use. c++ is not c. always prefer 'object is a value' thinking over 'pointer to object' if you can.

Comment: @RichardHodges: BTW, first solution may be written without pointers, so the main difference is exposing `std::function` vs exposing `<random>`.

Comment: That's a reasonable point, but surely if it's about hiding implementation details then a simple pimpl would do it, and would not require any std:: headers at all?